# Почему в разных языках программирования используют массивы разных размерностей при работе с OpenGL?

Tags: массивы, opengl

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему в примерах на С используют двумерный массив:

```
const GLfloat vertex_data[3][3] = {
    {  0.0,  1.0,  0.0  }, 
    { -1.0, -1.0,  0.0  }, 
    {  1.0, -1.0,  0.0  } };
```

, а в питоне просто запихивают в один список:

```
vertex_data = [
    0, 1, 0,
    -1, -1, 0,
    1, -1, 0
]
```

?

Comment: Скорее всего из-за того, что в `Python` создавать много массивов накладно.

Comment: @pank в Питоне нет массивов вообще, вместо них списки, но и то их не столь накладно создавать( если вы про ресурсы компьютера имели в виду).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Основная причина, это удобство манипулирования и оперирования данными. Разные языки предоставляют свой функционал для обработки данных. Но OpenGL всё равно на входе требует, чтобы все буферы (массивы), матрицы и т.д. были одномерными.

Например, при умножении матриц в программе их хранят в двумерных массивах и применяют двойную индексацию `a[i][j]` (что гораздо удобнее для большинства операций), а потом при передаче в OpenGL преобразовывают в одномерный массив (что, в случае со статичными двумерными массивами, идентично передаче указателя на первый элемент, т.к. элементы лежат "подряд").

Comment: спасибо большое за объяснение)

Comment: @Ришат пожалуйста, помечайте ответ птичкой как принятый )